# Count the frequency of unique elements in dataframe column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data frame `df` and have a column of strings called `words`. I need to count the frequency of each unique element in this column. How can I do this without counting the frequency of each unique string multiple times?

Comment: Do you have a string in each observation (line) of your data or just one word per observation?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 require(tidyverse)
 freq <- dataframe %>%
  group_by(words) %>%
  count()
```

You start with your dataframe, group_by gets each unique string in the column "words", and count() counts how many times each string appears.